# Reduce image quality in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I reduce the quality of an image using PHP ?

```html
upload_mode = @$this->setting->upload_mode?:'file';
            $upload_path = @$this->setting->upload_path?:'uploads/';

            $file               = Request::file($name);
            $fm                 = array();
            $fm['name']         = $_FILES[$name]['name'];                   
            $fm['ext']          = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fm['size']         = $_FILES[$name]['size'];
            $fm['content_type'] = $_FILES[$name]['type'];

            if($upload_mode=='database') {
                $fm['filedata']     = file_get_contents($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']);
                DB::table('cms_filemanager')->insert($fm);
                $id_fm              = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
                DB::table('cms_filemanager')->where('id',$id_fm)->update(['id_md5' =>md5($id_fm)]);
                $filename           = 'upload_virtual/files/'.md5($id_fm).'.'.$fm['ext'];
            }else{
                if(!file_exists($upload_path.date('Y-m'))) {
                    if(!mkdir($upload_path.date('Y-m'),0777)) {
                        die('Gagal buat folder '.$upload_path.date('Y-m'));
                    }
                }
                $filename = md5(str_random(12)).'.'.$fm['ext'];
                $file->move($upload_path.date('Y-m'),$filename);                        
                $filename = $upload_path.date('Y-m').'/'.$filename;
            }

            $url                = asset($filename);
```

have someone help me ? what i need add to make it work like what i need ?

Comment: Do you want to resize it, or just reduce the quality? Otherwise `imagejpeg()` would be quite a good solution: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Answer (score 3):

> GD is an open source code library for the dynamic creation of images
>   by programmers. GD is written in C, and "wrappers" are available for
>   Perl, PHP and other languages. GD creates PNG, JPEG and GIF images,
>   among other formats. GD is commonly used to generate charts, graphics,
>   thumbnails, and most anything else, on the fly.

Code to reduce file size for the image:

```
<?php 
    function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {

        $info = getimagesize($source);

        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

        imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

        return $destination;
    }

    $source_img = 'source.jpg';
    $destination_img = 'destination .jpg';

    $d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 90);
 ?>
$d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 90);
```

[Reference](https://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-reduce-image-file-size-while-uploading-using-php-code/)